# Limits and Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have no idea as to how to go about this. Could somebody please help?

Let $$\displaystyle A=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+1}+\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+4}+\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+9}\cdots+\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+n^{2}}\right)$$
Find
$$\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{A}\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$$

Comment: Limit i think is $\pi/2$

Comment: Do you know about the limit definition of an integral, If no i can try to explain but its a whole of a big concept , if yes. Factor out a $n^2$ from denominator. You'd get an easy definite integral with limits 0 to 1 having anti derivative $2 tan^{-1}x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+1}+\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+4}+\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+9}\cdots+\dfrac{2n}{n^{2}+n^{2}}\right)$

Given limit is this , First of all we will try to put in a simple more convenient summation form.

As you can see , the series in denominator is $r^2$ which is followed by the term $n^2$.

We will factor $2$ from numerator and $n^2$ from denominator , I will just write a single term instead of writing whole thing.

$T_r=2 \;\;*\;\;\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}*\dfrac{1}{1+\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^2}$

Writing this in summation form,

$ lim_{x\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n}*\dfrac{1}{1+\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)^2}$

Now, I want you to recall definition, of a Reimann integral.

If you'd remember we take a very small area of a rectangle , parallelogram or anything, in a small width , here that width is comparable $\frac{1}{n}$ and the function or $x$ value which tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ , You can see it aswell. Hence we can replace this by an equivalent integral.

$\int_0^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ and oh, don't forget the $2$, in front.

Comment: Please note that this is not very rigorous, but i hope you get the intuition, the rest is pretty easy, requires only a simple trick with integral.

Comment: I am just 17 , I wouldn't like to be sir yet. But let me edit. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Let me just add another answer, but note that I wouldn't like to solve everything, since this would be against site's policy but i will give you a hint for this one.

$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{x}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$             $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $eq(1)$

Let the $Int (I)$ be denoted by $f(x)$ though this is completely incorrect in general sense but it's only for intuition.

Then a property state that,

$f(x)=f(a+b-x)$ where a,b are upper and lower limits of integral.

This gives,

$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\pi/2-x}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}dx$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $eq(2)$

Now, simply add $eq(1)$ and $eq(2)$.

You have to take it from here.

Comment: Well, the books , you see i am not really an jee aspirant and etc, I don't like don't exams. I just like every book I see. But I used Arihant question bank for math, Pradeep , Hc verma for physics and Modern, TMH for chemistry. And you can use same account on stack chat  as in here, just try to login there.

Comment: XD with whom you are talking?